# Recursive Data types in sml

Tags: recursion, sml, smlnj, abstract-data-type, recursive-datastructures

Is there a way define a datatype for whole numbers. i.e. 0,1,2,... not zero, one ,... individually.

I want to define the set of whole numbers. bu using 0, n,n+1 with recursion.
I tried something like this: datatype nat=0|n|n+1 . But it was nearly obvious not to work because it does not recognize 0 as integer right?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the set of natural numbers is countably infinite, you can't enumerate all the cases.

You can represent natural numbers conceptually by [Peano numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Peano_axioms):

```
datatype peano = Zero | Succ of peano
```

The datatype is very simple, it only defines `0` and ensures that each natural number has a successor. For example, 2 is actually represented as `Succ (Succ Zero)`.

```
fun count Zero = 0
  | count (Succ p) = 1 + count p
```

Use similar techniques, you can build up `add`, `sub`, `mult` functions like you have with natural numbers.

Comment: Yes, but I need to use a data type that uses 0,1,2,3 and not succ(succ(succ(zer0))). 
So can I take that as no, not possible for infinite 0,1,2,... ?

Comment: @user1710036 Why do you need that representation, if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: Why do you need that representation?
Its not a representation. 
I want to have a datatype for natural numbers. That's all. 
And I dont want to input succ(succ(succ(succ(0)))) which is tidious.